# How does Ember data's generic shouldSave and RESTAdapter's shouldSave functions work?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember data's DS.Store has a `filter` function that calls `adapter.shouldSave(record)` ([github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L668)). In the case of using Ember data's RESTAdapter, the RESTAdapter's `shouldSave` function is called.

`shouldSave` returns `!reference.parent`  ([github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L92)) where `reference` seems to be just like the record from the debugging I've done. But I couldn't find the `parent` of the reference I was working with.

Question 1: Does anyone know what `return !reference.parent` means here for the RESTAdapter?

---

Question 2: What does the `Ember.K` mean in the generic Ember data Adapter's `shouldSave` ([see github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L689))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: Does anyone know what return !reference.parent means here for the RESTAdapter?

After reading trough the source the line `return !reference.parent` basically means that `reference` is the record that is being currently handled and `parent` would point to it's parent in the case the record is a child of a parent model having `hasMany` / `belongsTo` relationships.

Example:

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
  comments: DS.hasMany('App.Comment')
});

App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  post: DS.belongsTo('App.Post')
});
```

In the example a record of type `App.Comment` has as it's parent `App.Post`. So this line makes perfect sense `return !reference.parent` which would return `false` is the reference does not have a parent a thus not being part of any relationship.

> Question 2: What does the Ember.K mean in the generic Ember data Adapter's shouldSave (see github)?

`Ember.K` simply is a function returning `this`. See [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/3b60016c2b6b38646d954014d10f74fcfe1a3d54/packages/ember-metal/lib/core.js#L101) for reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Almost clear ... so why does the condition of the record not having a parent relate to the record should be saved?

Comment: well, depending on which other functions do call the `shouldSave` method on the adapter there would be then more work to do if the record in question has a parent, makes sense?

Comment: have also a look here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L661 that is a place where `shouldSave` is called

Comment: I know `shouldSave` is called in the DS.Store's [`save`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L661), but there are no mentioning of parents in that (`save`) function, so what difference does having a parent or not make here in the `save` function?

Comment: the difference seams obvious since the record not having a parent will be added to the `filteredSet` returned by the `save` function

Comment: in other words, whatever other function calls the `save` method on the adapter will receive back only records without a parent

Comment: yes, I understand the logic, but I don't understand the purpose. WHY are the records with parents excluded in the returned filtered set?  ... I am missing the big picture here. Thanks!

Comment: I guess they are excluded because records having a parent will be saved along with the parent, for example when defining the `embedded: 'always'`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32983/discussion-between-haoqi-li-and-intuitivepixel)

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer! I would love to continue with the chat, but it's 2:28 AM (local time barcelona) and I need some sleep now :)

Comment: no worries. It's not urgent. :) I'm just being curious that's all. Take your time.  Thank YOU for staying up and answering my question after question. :D